# How to package LaTeX source in a DEB package?

Tags: packaging, latex, documentation

I need to include a PDF documentation file in a DEB package. And I think LaTeX source might fix my needs, since I want someone to contribute to the source.

But I don't know how to make a PDF in packaging process with LaTeX source. Any example?

Comment: One doesn't usually include the source of the documentation in a package, but the documentation itself. Any particular reason you want to go the other way around?

Comment: I mean the documentation source is remain in the source code, because I want to invite people to contribute to the documentation content. While I want it to be compiled when the process of *debianization* is going. Seems like I have found something like this but I forgot where it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be particularly difficult, you could override `dh_auto_build`. For example, here's how I add a manpage:

```
$ cat debian/rules
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
    dh $@ --with config-package

override_dh_auto_build:
    ronn -r docs/myprogram.ronn --organization="Example, Inc." --date=`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`
    dh_auto_build
```

(`docs/myprogram.8` is part of my `manpages` file.)

---

You could write a script which builds the PDF:

```
#! /bin/bash
cd path/to/doc/sources
xelatex doc.tex
bibtex doc
xelatex doc.tex
xelatex doc.tex
```

And then, to your `install` file, add:

```
path/to/doc/sources/doc.pdf usr/share/doc/mypackage/
```

And then, in your `debian/rules` file:

```
override_dh_auto_build:
    path/to/that/script.sh
    dh_auto_build
```

(Of course, with perhaps overriding the `clean` rules as well.)

---

If you use a makefile to build your tex documents, then this could be simplified by having your overall makefile also build the docs for the default rule, and the only specify the path in the `install` file.

Comment: OK, thank you so much. Then, what about CMake? Because I use cmake build system.